# How to solve ResourceNotFoundException in ListView Music file

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set music files from raw folder to play in listViews that open to a NewActivity.
I have configured the Model class, MainActivity and ListviewAdapter but i still get the error. maybe i'm getting it wrong somewhere.
Please help me with a fix. Thanks for your time.

**Model Class**

```js
public class Model {

    String title;
    String desc;
    int icon;
    int soundfile;
    String brandNewDesc;



    //constructor
    public Model(String title, String desc, String description, int icon, int music) {
        this.title = title;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.icon = icon;
        this.soundfile = music;
        this.brandNewDesc = description;
    }

    //getters


    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public String getBrandNewDesc(){

        return brandNewDesc;
    }

    public int getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public int getSoundfile() {
        return soundfile;
    }
```

**From MainActivity.java**

```js
 MusicFile= new int[] {R.raw.song_1,R.raw.song_2,R.raw.song_3, R.raw.song_4,R.raw.song_5,R.raw.song_6,R.raw.song_7,R.raw.song_8,};
        //Listview icons for song titles in position
        icon = new int[]{ R.drawable.song, R.drawable.song, R.drawable.song, R.drawable.song,R.drawable.song,R.drawable.song, R.drawable.song,R.drawable.song,};

        listView = findViewById(R.id.list);

        for (int i = 0; i< title.size(); i++){
            Model model =new Model(title.get(i), description.get(i), newDesc.get(i), icon[i], MusicFile[i]);
            //bind all strings in an array
            arrayList.add(model);
        }

        //pass result to listview class
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, arrayList);

        //bind the adapter to the listview class
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**From ListViewAdapter.java**

```js
//listview soundfile file for songs in position
        soundfile= new int[] {R.raw.song_1,R.raw.song_2,R.raw.song_3, R.raw.song_4,R.raw.song_5,R.raw.song_6,R.raw.song_7,R.raw.song_8,};

        //listview item clicks
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //code later
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NewActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", modellist.get(i).getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("brandNewDesc", modellist.get(i).getBrandNewDesc());
                intent.putExtra("soundfile", modellist.get(i).getSoundfile());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);


            }
        });


        return view;
```

**NewActivity.java**

```js
// setting up media players


    public void  play(View v) {
        if (player == null) {
            //then here, I sent the position of the chosen song in the intent extras.
            //the get back the extra
            int position = 0;
            try{
                position=getIntent().getIntExtra("soundfile",0);
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String fileToPlay="song_"+position;




            player = MediaPlayer.create(this, getResources().getIdentifier(fileToPlay,"raw",getPackageName()));
            Toast.makeText(this, "Hymn Tune Playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
```

**This is my LogCat**

```js
 Process: com.gritchen.redeemedsongs, PID: 28671
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:389)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6748)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25458)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6549)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:888)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6748) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25458) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6549) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:220)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.openRawResourceFd(ResourcesImpl.java:317)
        at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResourceFd(Resources.java:1293)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:980)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:963)
        at com.gritchen.redeemedsongs.NewActivity.play(NewActivity.java:89)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6748) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25458) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6549) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:888)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, you put resource identifier into intent for "soundfile" key, but expect position when get it from there. Try to create MediaPlayer like this

```
MediaPlayer.create(this, position)
```

Comment: Where please explain further. Thanks

Comment: Please don't stress yourself any further to explain. Your are more than a million times correct. Thanks a lot...